# JQuery Navigation Menu Animation with Wordpress Page List

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animation, menu, hover

So I am using Jquery to display a pop up menu on my current site. The html is a wordpress wp_list_pages output for all you wordpress types out there. For all you non-wordpress types, this means that wordpress will output nested ul & li elements in accordance with page architecture on wordpress. Bottom line, I want the jquery code to be wordpress compatible, so if I change the pages, the code will handle this.

I want the code to be lite but the following is a bit janky. Any better ideas? Plus I want the pop up menu only to appear after the mouse has hovered over the ul element for 1000ms (1s), but not otherwise. Thoughts?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.fn.pauseit = function(duration) {
        jQuery(this).animate({ dummy: 1 }, duration);
        return this;
};
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("div#access li.page_item ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix 

    jQuery("div#access li.page_item").hover(

        function(){
             jQuery(this).find('ul:first').pauseit(1000).css({/*visibility: "visible",display: "none"*/}).fadeIn('fast');
        },

        function(){
             jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({/*visibility: "hidden",*/}).fadeOut('fast');

        }
    ); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i discovered hoverIntent at http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. This resolved my problem.